# I'm trying to resize an image using css to be mobile friendly but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize an image to be mobile friendly but it doesn't resize. I'm using a template for my website and I modified it a lot but maybe the already written code is what's preventing the photo form resizing

I've already tried using width=100% and object-fit:scale-down and  tags but it all didn't work.

```
 <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('img/slider-2.jpg'); overflow: scroll; width:100%">
```

I think it should shrink the photo and keep its dimensions but what happens is that part of the photo gets covered when I resize the browser or when i open it on a mobile phone

Comment: Can you please share this in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Which part of the code ? all the css and js with this html page or do you want specific parts ?

Comment: `width=100%` is not valid CSS, you need to write `width: 100%`

Comment: i want all codes.. bcoz need to see & visualize the design..

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, sorry .
I wrote it write in the code

Comment: @Manikandan2811 no he shouldn't post all codes. Only the relevant ones. Otherwise they post all their html + css

Comment: But I have multiple pages for the CSS and JS what should I  do ?
Could you help me with that please ?

Comment: ok.. i understood.. but i need only css and html codes, only for image part?

Comment: Oh, I got a problem with that .
The photos don't show in codepen

Comment: wheather the image is in <img> tag or background image?

Comment: It's a background image in a div as shown in the code above

Comment: can u plz send me the width and height of the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.. it will work..

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-item">
    <img src="img/slider-2.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
```

**css**

```
 body {
    margin:0px;
 }
 .slider-item {
    text-align: center;
 }
 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Well, as a concept, it worked and thanks a ton for that .
The problem is , there was some text over it but it disappeared. Can you tell me why that happened

Comment: ~~~
<section class="home-slider owl-carousel" style="object-fit: scale-down;">
    
        
        <div class="slider-item">
            <img src="img/slider-2.jpg" alt="">
            <h1>WE ARE HERE<br>FOR YOUR CARE</h1>
              <p>Save your time and your money, we will handle that for your <br> business safety.</p>
          
         </div>
</section>
~~~

Comment: Plus it leaves a huge whitespace under it when it shrinks

Comment: Do u want the text over the image? or below the image?

Comment: I want it to appear over the image(on it not under it) And thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Try it, maybe it's work. If it's not, that's mean you have problems with your parent div element and please send some of code from your template.

Comment: What parts of code should i send
Consider that I have many css and js pages not only one

Comment: add this to first lines of your css after that if it's not work send here css lines where you affect to images.

Comment: I just noticed something
The image isn't just inserted 
It's a div container and has a background image 
Can this be the reason that functions don't work on it ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slider-item{
  width:100%;
  background-size:100%;
  (OR)
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('img/slider-2.jpg');">
```

Comment: add : min-height:250px;

Answer (score 0):

Please try this codes.. i modified some codes..

**HTML**

```
<section class="home-slider owl-carousel" style="object-fit: scale-down;">
    <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="img/slider-2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slider-item-description">
            <h1>WE ARE HERE<br>FOR YOUR CARE</h1>
            <p>Save your time and your money, we will handle that for your <br> business safety.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    section {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .home-slider .slider-item {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .slider-item-description {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: #fff;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Depends upon the image size, the content will aligned from both sides.. and try to add the same height and width images for all..

Comment: Thank you very much it works!!
I'm sorry but there's still one problem. 
When it shrinks to phone size the text appears under the photo. 
If you could do that i'd be really grateful

Comment: .slider-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: Please add that css code and add more height images.. like height:1000px

Comment: I can't understand this ?:(

Comment: In css .slider-item img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

Comment: Please add heigh resolution images.. minimum the image has above 1000px height

Comment: OK i understand now. Thanks

Comment: no mention.. its just sharing our knowledges.. thanks for ur co-operation..  if u have any doubt plz ask us..